# Spark Deserializing Object On Every Map Call

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to create a spark RDD with one row per file for a bunch of text files stored in s3. I'm doing this by creating an instance of `AmazonS3` to get the text file content. I've created a serializable wrapper around this S3 client so that it can be used in a map function of spark:

```
class SerializableAmazonS3 implements java.io.Serializable {

    public transient AmazonS3 client;
    public AmazonS3 create()
    {
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3Client.builder().withRegion(REGION).withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        return builder.build();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) {
        this.create();
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that spark calls `readObject` for every row (every time the function inside of `map()` is called. Is this just expected behavior for `RDD#map`? I'd like to have the object only deserialized once per node if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Hadoop/EMR S3 filesystem client, you'll get the benefit of the caching of the FS instances & so you'll only get one FS instance (and AWS s3 client) per (URI, user) pair. This is critical as the AWS lib & needs a pool of threads to work properly: it's not a low-cost object instance

Comment: I had heard there were some performance problems with using the S3 filesystem client. Particularly with downloading lots of smaller files. [See here for an example](http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219)

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot though.

Comment: For small files the time spent opening them via a GET Is > the read time. You also get billed something like 0.4c/GET, so you don't want thousands of small files. Best to merge them into a partitionable file format. Hadoop har are like .tar files which can be processed, though I've not done in in Spark & S3

Answer (score 0):

map() transformation in spark is executed for each row in a text file/or your source. The other options you have is using mapPartition(), this transformation is called once per partition. Also, in your particular case, you can call the coalesce(num_of_partition) and this will create only so many partition you specify and after this step you can think of calling mapPartition().

Hope it helps:

How mapPartition() works, see below:

http://www.mishudi.com/general-spark-transformation/#mapPartitions

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MapReduce , spark Map doesn't provides a setup cleanup and map phase.

You have to apply custom logic to perform setup and cleanup .

Few logics are (just trying to mimic setup, map and cleanup of Map Reduce)

> 1. Have a try catch loop and call cleaup in the final block . Shutdown hook is also a alternative to acheieve the same
> 2. have the map call in the try catch
> 3. The first line of try catch checks for a boolean initialize variable (set to false initially) and calls a setup method and sets
>      this variable to  true.

Please find a example below of Spark writing to Aerospike in the Map task . 
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/write-to-aerospike-from-spark/

Inside Map task, spark initializes aerosike client, dose some action for every input row . closes the connection when the map task complete.

Pay attention that in Spark all task are thread and not process , so use static variables wisely.